# How do you test in app purchases? the way I'm doing it now is really slow

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

So right now I have a real product and all my code is the same as it would be for productions but I have setup a test account. I make the purchase in the app, then I go to the merchant account and cancel the order, then it takes about 40 minutes for the order to be totally cancelled before I can test my purchase again.

Surely there is a better way to do this?

EDIT: I was wrong, I wish it took 40 minutes, at this point I don't even know how long it takes, but it is a lot longer than 40 minutes.

Comment: unfortunately there is no real way to do it. Google suggests to use dummy states for purchase which is not connected with your real item in the google_play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not wait 40 minutes, I created new products in the Google Play Developer Console. This way you don't need to wait, you just go there, create one product and test it. Then um cancel the order, create another product and move on.

I know its no optimal, but...

Comment: Yeah that is what I was thinking of doing but thought surely there must be another way, glad to know I'm not the only one in this boat.